# Remove coefficients of the highest frequencies from fft()

Tags: matlab, for-loop, fft, frequency

I got a file with ECG noise, and I need to remove the coefficients of the highest frequencies in a fft.
I can then use IFFT, and make sure the function only contains real numbers. The result should be a file with the filtered ECG.
My code so far:

```
function [Z] = cutout (X, m)  %X= the noise file, m the frequency
Y = fft(X);

% transforms X via an FFt and save it in Y
[rows cols] =size(Y);%get size of Y

Y=abs(Y);


for i=1:cols
    if Y(i)> m; % if freq Y(i) is higher than m make it 0 
        Y(i)=0;
    end
end
Z=abs(ifft(Y));
%Calculates the ifft of the modified Y and sets all
%complex numbers to real numbers
end
```

I do not understand where I go wrong, does anyone have an idea or suggestion?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3):

First thing's first. By removing the coefficients of the highest frequencies, you're applying a FIR (finite impulse response) low pass filter to your data. You may achieve better results with a more sophisticated filter than a simple zeroing of the highest frequency components. There is a tremendous amount of information available on filter selection, design, and application in MATLAB which you can easily find online.

Now, on to your question. You have several issues with the code you presented:

- You should not take `abs(Y)`. The FFT is complex even for real input data.
- The values of `Y` are frequency amplitudes, not the frequency numbers. You're removing the frequencies with the largest amplitude rather than the highest frequencies.
- If you have real data, you should use `Z=ifft(Y,'symmetric')` to ensure a real result rather than taking the absolute value of the answer. This will preserve negative numbers in your result which would become positive if you use `abs`.
- Since you're getting the size of `Y` as `[rows, cols]` it seems like `Y` may be a 2D array. You should be very careful using `fft` with multidimensional arrays to make sure you're doing what you mean to. `fft` operates over the first non-singleton dimension.

What you actually need to do is figure out which values of `Y` correspond to the highest frequencies and zero out those values. For a vector of size `N`, the frequency vector is given by

```
k = ifftshift(-floor(N/2):floor(N/2-1));
```

You can verify this by taking the FFT of functions where you know the expected result. For example the FFT of `[1 1 1 1]` should be nonzero only at the 0 frequency, the FFT of `[-1 1 -1 1]` should be nonzero at the highest frequency. You can test more cases using specific numbers of `x` values in [0,2*pi) and various sine or cosine functions `y=sin(k*x)`

Assuming `X` is a 1d vector you could get your result via

```
N = length(X);
k = ifftshift(-floor(N/2):floor((N-1)/2)); %//compute the frequency vector
Y = fft(X); %//perform fft
Y = Y.*(abs(k)<=m); %// zero out all frequencies larger than 'm'
Z = ifft(Y,'symmetric');
```

Comment: Worth noting that the `Y = Y .* H(k);` line is applying a circular FIR filter, using multiplication in the frequency domain (which corresponds to circular convolution in time).  `H(k) = (k<m)` is of course a "brickwall" lowpass filter.

Answer (score -1):

The FFT is complex. If you take the absolute value you, you lose information.

```
function [Z] = cutout (X, m) 
  % X the noise file, m the frequency 

  % FFT
  Y = fft(X);

  % Transform
  Y(abs(Y)>m) = 0;

  % IFFT
  Z = abs(ifft(Y));

end
```

Comment: This removes the strongest frequencies, not high frequencies.